# Insert same value in all elements of field in a SQLite query

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have some 750 rows in my sqlite table. I am adding a new field **localPath** into it. I have to insert the same string **default** in the field as value. How to insert this value for 750 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

`UPDATE table SET localPath = 'default'`